# La lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Requiero que en mi tabla agrupe con el campo folio mis registros y orden por la fecha de inserción mas nueva.
En mi tabla tengo contenido la información de folios con sus campos respectivos, esos folios se repiten por que puede que el estatus de ellas cambien, (no puedo hacer un update por que requiero del histórico del folio para saber en que etapas estuvo), entonces lo que necesito es realizar una consulta  en donde me muestre los folios (sin repetirse) con la etapa mas reciente (el registro mas nuevo de ese folio) con la fecha de creación yo se cual es el mas reciente de ese folio.

En MySQL no tendría problema con colocar una consulta `select * from [FoliosSustitutos] group by [folio_original] order by [created_at] desc`, pero en el jodido SQL Server no funciona así.
Me marca La columna 'libreria' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY. tengo entendido que tendría que colocar en el group by todos los campos, pero si las fechas de creación son distintas pues obvio que el registro ya no es igual con el otro y cuando ejecuto el query me salen los folios repetidos.

Comment: El comportamiento de MySQL para las agrupaciones va contra el estándar ANSI, no funciona así en ningún otro motor de base de datos

Comment: Agrega las columnas al order by...

Answer (score 1):

Remarco lo que ya te ha dicho Lamak, el "jodido" no es SQL Server, que en este apartado sigue el estándar ANSI, como lo hacen la mayoría de los motores. Si solo te interesa obtener el `folio_original` y la más nueva `created_at` la forma habitual es:

```
SELECT folio_original,
       MAX(created_at) as created_at
       FROM FoliosSustitutos
       GROUP BY folio_original
```

Agrupamos por `folio_original` y usamos una función de agregación `MAX`para obtener la última fecha de cada grupo. Cualquier columna que esté en el `SELECT` y no dentro de una función de agregación, tiene que estar en el `GROUP_BY`.

Ahora si lo que quieres es obtener la última fila por cada grupo, sin duda la respuesta de Lamak es la justa. Eventualmente en versiones antiguas de SQL Server, puede que no dispongas de `ROW_NUMBER()` o de una `CTE`, para esas oportunidades, la solución a medias sería hacer algo así:

```
SELECT *
       FROM FoliosSustitutos F
       INNER JOIN (SELECT folio_original,
                          MAX(created_at) as created_at
                          FROM FoliosSustitutos
                          GROUP BY folio_original
              ) G
              ON G.folio_original = F.folio_original
              AND G.created_at = created_at
```

Digo que es una solución a medias, por que si eventualmente tienes dos fechas iguales por `folio_original` te traería los dos registros.

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Folio_Original 
                                    ORDER BY created_at DESC) 
    FROM dbo.FoliosSustitutos
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
;
```